# Add many address in CC from csv file POWERSHELL

Tags: powershell, csv, email

I have a problem with a script in powershell.
In particular, I would need to add more CC addresses when sending the mail. The addresses are present in the csv file (in the csv file I have 5 columns and the separator used is the comma ","). In the cc field of the csv file I entered multiple addresses separating them with a space "". Unfortunately the script in the phase of sending the email reads only the last of one address in the cc even if there are many addresses in the csv.

This is my csv file - Example of my csv

```
AOO,Piva,Email,CC
ASI,01234567890,mail1@mail,mail2@mail mail3@mail mail4@mail
```

And this is my script - Powershell script

```
#Importo il file csv  con idcodie e email in una variabile $EmailList
$csvfile = "C:\Fatture_in_errore\lista.csv"
#Importo tutto il csv in una variabile chiamata EmailList 
$EmailList = IMPORT-CSV $csvfile

#Ciclo i record nel csv

$IndirizzoEmail = Import-Csv $csvfile | Where-Object {$_."Piva"-eq $idcodice} 
$IndirizzoEmail."Email"
$IndirizzoEmail."CC"
$IndirizzoEmail."AOO"

$EmailCsv = $IndirizzoEmail."Email"
$EmailCC = $IndirizzoEmail."CC"
#Valorizzo le variabili codice ed email e individuo il destinatario a cui inviare il file xml
$To = $EmailCsv
$CC = $EmailCC

$message = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage 
$message.From = $From 
$message.To.Add($To)
$message.CC.Add($CC)
$message.IsBodyHtml = $True 
$message.Subject = $Subject
$attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment) 
$message.Attachments.Add($attach) 
$message.body = $Body 
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver) 
$smtp.Send($message)
```

Many thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

If I look at your CSV file, I can see that the email addresses at 'CC' are separated by a space. They need to be separated by a comma.

```
$CC = $EmailCC.Split(" ") -join ","
```

If you would add the above at line 17. the addresses will be separated correctly.

Comment: Hi Bernard,
now the script works! Many Thanks, Andrea